# How to interpret and use Emokit data?

Tags: signal-processing, emokit

I am using EmoKit (https://github.com/openyou/emokit) to retrieve data. The sample data looks like as follows:

```
+========================================================+
| Sensor |   Value  | Quality  | Quality L1 | Quality L2 |
+--------+----------+----------+------------+------------+
|   F3   |   -768   |   5672   |    None    |  Excellent  |
|   FC5  |   603    |   7296   |    None    |  Excellent  |
|   AF3  |   311    |   7696   |    None    |  Excellent  |
|   F7   |   -21    |   296    |  Nothing   |  Nothing   |
|   T7   |   433    |   104    |  Nothing   |  Nothing   |
|   P7   |   581    |   7592   |    None    |  Excellent  |
|   O1   |   812    |   7760   |    None    |  Excellent  |
|   O2   |   137    |   6032   |    None    |  Excellent  |
|   P8   |   211    |   5912   |    None    |  Excellent  |
|   T8   |   -51    |   6624   |    None    |  Excellent  |
|   F8   |   402    |   7768   |    None    |  Excellent  |
|   AF4  |   -52    |   7024   |    None    |  Excellent  |
|   FC6  |   249    |   6064   |    None    |  Excellent  |
|   F4   |   509    |   5352   |    None    |  Excellent  |
|   X    |    -2    |   N/A    |    N/A     |    N/A     |
|   Y    |    0     |   N/A    |    N/A     |    N/A     |
|   Z    |    ?     |   N/A    |    N/A     |    N/A     |
|  Batt  |    82    |   N/A    |    N/A     |    N/A     |
+--------+----------+----------+------------+------------+
|Packets Received:  3101    |  Packets Processed:  3100  |
|   Sampling Rate:   129    |        Crypto Rate:   129  |
+========================================================+
```

Are these values in micro-volts? If so, how can these be more than 200 microvolts? The EEG data is in the range of 0-200 microvolts. Or does this require some kind of processing? If so what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [frequently asked questions of emokit](https://github.com/openyou/emokit#frequently-asked-questions), :

> - *What unit is the data I'm getting back in? How do I get volts out of it?*
>
> One least-significant-bit of the fourteen-bit value you get back is 0.51 microvolts. See the specification for more details.

Looking for the details in the [specification (via archive.org)](https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20140702044435/http://emotiv.com/upload/manual/EPOCSpecifications.pdf), we find the following for the "Emotiv EPOC Neuroheadset":

> ```
> Resolution                      |  14 bits 1 LSB = 0.51μV (16 bit ADC, 
>                                 |  2 bits instrumental noise ﬂoor discarded)
> Dynamic range (input referred)  |  8400μV (pp)
> ```

As a validation we can check that for a 14 bits linear ADC, the 8400 microvolts (peak-to-peak) would be divided in steps of `8400 / 16384` or approximately 0.5127 microvolts.

For the Epoc+, the [comparison chart](https://www.emotiv.com/comparison/) indicates a 14-bit and a 16-bit version (with a +/- 4.17mV dynamic range or 8340 microvolts peak-to-peak). The 16-bit version would then have raw data steps of  `8340 / 65536` or approximately 0.127 microvolts. If that is what you are using, then the largest value of 812 you listed would correspond to `812 * 0.127 = 103` microvolts.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the rationale here. I have an Emotiv Epoc 1.0 (not Epoc+). In some resources on the net (https://www.emotiv.com/forums/topic/Insight_Sample_EEG_data/), it's mentioned that raw sensor data is offset by 4100 microvolts. Do you think this should be removed from the readings as well? Or should I apply bandpass filter (in frequency domain) to take care of this?

Comment: You'd have to do that on the Emotiv data, but [emokit does that for you](https://github.com/openyou/emokit/blob/master/python/emokit/packet.py#L55).

Comment: Thanks @SleuthEye.